# Nested methods within a class (and using Proc)

Tags: ruby, nested, proc

Am trying to do the following:

```
class Tester
  def some_test
    Proc.new do
      def prep_test
      end

      def do_test
      end

      def pass?
      end
    end
  end

  def another_test
    Proc.new ..
      ...
    end
  end

  # tests are mapped in array_of_tests

  def run
    array_of_tests.each do |t|
      t.call.prep_test
      t.call.do_test
      t.call.pass?
    end
  end
end

Tester.new.run
```

But when I start trying to execute each test `t`, I get something like:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `prep_test' for nil:NilClass
```

In experimenting, I found that this worked:

```
def test3
  Proc.new do
    def prep
      "running test3: prep"
    end

    def run
      "running test3: run"
    end

    def verify
      "running test3: verify"
    end
  end
end

t = test3
t.call.prep
t.call.run
t.call.verify
```

But this wasn't inside a class.

What am I missing to reference the nested methods inside `some_test` to make `Tester.new.run` work?

Comment: How does the array_of_tests look before you call method 'run' on class instance ? Now, I think array_of_tests is nil so it caused an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh!

```
def homer
  Class.new do
    def beer
      puts 'mmmm beer'
    end

    def donuts
      puts 'aaaauugggh dooooooooonuts!'
    end
  end    
end

homer.new.beer
```

If you need to pass any variables, do it the old fashioned way.

The Tester methods are outside the scope of the anonymous class you have generated.

But what you can do is use instance variables to have a reference to tester.

```
class Scenario
  def test3
    Class.new do
      attr_reader :environment
      def initialize environment
        @environment = environment
      end

      def run
        environment.blah
      end
    end
  end
end

scenario = Scenario.new
scenario.test3.new(scenario).run
```

Comment: Thanks for setting me on the right track: I have put the equivalent of ``homer`` inside my class ``Tester``. It fails when code inside my equivalent of ``beer`` and ``donuts`` are trying to access methods that are defined within ``Tester``. Does the ``Class.new`` put these methods outside the scope of code inside ``beer`` and ``donuts``?

Comment: Updated answer, I fail at stackoverflow. But if you're doing all this you might as well start using Test::Unit in Ruby

Answer (score 0):

This will also work

```
class Tester
  def some_test
    Proc.new do
      def Object.prep_test
      end

      def Object.do_test
      end

      def Object.pass?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Just to clarify what's going on in your two examples; when you execute the `Proc` it defines the methods on whatever class happens to be executing it. So in the first example, it defines them on the `Tester` class. In the second example, it defines them on `Object`. The second example only works because the `NilClass` class inherits from `Object`, so even though the `Proc` is returning a `nil`, you can still call those methods on it.

Basically, you can't store methods in a `Proc` like that. The fact that it worked in the second example is a total fluke.

Comment: Thanks @Doydle: unfortunately, still not working. Am still getting ``NoMethodError: undefined method `prep_test' for nil:NilClass``.

Ok, going back to basics: within ``Tester``, I would like to create a component that represents a test. This test will have sub-components that can be invoked (e.g. prep the test, run it, check if pass?). Tests can be stored in an array and executed.

Happy to do it using other approaches :)